# TFS Build Pipelines not queuing after detach/reattach of collection

Tags: tfs, devops

We detached one of our main collections and it failed to detach so we restarted it and everything appeared to be fine.  But we found this morning that the Build pipelines are not picking up new builds.  The build servers are communicating and showing online but nothing is queuing.  Anyone ever experience this during a detach/reattach process?

Comment: Did you restart the build agents?

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Customer quiesced and unquiesced TFS and that fixed the pipeline issues.

---

Detach/reattach collection usually will not effect build related.

First, suggest you to take a look at **Event View** if there are some useful logs for troubleshooting.

If you are using vNext build, check the agent pool and agents which should all be **green**.

Make sure in your build definition, you have selected the right agent queue. Also try to create an **empty build definition with no build task** to see if the issue is related to the definition. And also restart your agent service on your TFS server.

Also check if the service ***[Visual Studio Team Foundation Background Job Agent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252450(v=vs.120).aspx)*** is running. If not, start it manually and try the build again.

[image]

*Note: The service is running in TFS server, not build server.*

For **logs** to troubleshooting , check the ***event view*** and  the log in `\agent_diag` on build agent to see whether there are some useful information.

If you still get this issue, then deploy and configure a totally new build agent. This will help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: I quiesced and unquiesced TFS and that fixed the pipeline issues.